# Ubuntu 18.04.4 login loop

Tags: login

I post this because I couldn't find a question similar to what I am experiencing. Please redirect me, if there is one already.

The login loop started couple of months ago. My Ubuntu is setup to not show the login screen at all since there are no other users. After a system update the laptop was restarted and ever since I am getting greeted with this more often than not. I've been into few forums searching, but I don't have much time to research. Also I started giving up when I had to switch consoles. Both Ctrl+Alt+F2 and Ctrl+Alt+F3 show strange behavior - when I activate them I can only see the top left cursor blinking on a blank screen. No typing seems to be able to change that. Then Ctrl+Alt+F7 brings me back to my login loop, where I restart the laptop. Then going through the GRUB's menu and another restart I am able to enter the system as usual.

Any ideas?
The laptop is a 13yd Lenovo T61 and an upgraded HDD around a year ago.

Comment: I would firstly check you have sufficient space in your user directory, this is usually achieved via switching to a terminal, login and entering commands. If you don't like using a terminal, you could boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media), navigate to your hdd/ssd & check from the 'live' media (it'll take longer, and ensure you have space in your ssd/hdd & you're not looking at the 'live' system's created directories in RAM).

Comment: I have divided my hdd into 3 parts for this installation:
1st - linux-swap;
2nd - root dir;
3rd - a user dir, or at least I believe it should be, since I only access and store things here.

Strangely enough I've just checked my file manager and it says that my root dir is full at 99%, but my GParted claims it still has about 6% of free space. 
Which I don't think is much, but I never imagined that 60GBs won't be enough for this installation, where I only do browsing and occasionally text editing and some video.
Should I look somewhere for odd folders?

Comment: Today the root partition shows as follows:

File manager - around 35% free space
GParted - around 37% free space

,,,

Comment: if you create separate partitions for directories (eg. /home for user directories (this excludes root user though but that account is disabled by default in Ubuntu) data saved in those goes to whatever partition you allocated (via `fstab` [file system table] or during install) and everything else goes to / (the fallback). All additional software will be loaded on / for normal installations, so the more software you add the more space you need. Minimum specifications assume no-to-minimal additional software is needed.

Comment: Details you provided such as your last comment `gparted` and %s mean nothing to me, as I cannot see how or if used and you didn't say. A 60GB / partition should be heaps (my own is 32gb & I have three desktops installed) but certain programs can create temporary files, which will be cleaned by in subsequent boots etc.. so space will or does change. There are commands that will re-claim the space (hurry what will occur in due course anyway), but your issue may not be space related - it's first thing I check with a login loop (next is change I made prior 2 sessions to software config/stack)

Comment: Alright, there is an update. I have upgraded the 18.04 to 20.04.1 now. The issue remains. Out of 56 gigs of total disk partition for root, the Ubuntu installation is using around 15 gigs. When the login loop appears I have two files in the /var/log directory (kern.log & syslog) taking the rest of the free space of 42 gigs, both files of equal size of around 20gigs. Deleting those files solves the problem for couple of boots and then they eat up the space again for another loop.